# Is it possible to save object in two different schemas using single hibernate session?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, sessionfactory

I am trying to persist person object into two different schemas using single hibernate session as follows

I have Person Class having certain fields in it

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

//getters and setters methods
```

Now I need to save the object into two different schemas using single hibernate session. Can this happens, 
can anybody have any idea please help me.

Comment: You have to use 2 separate session for 2 schema

Comment: @chesh OP's question is not about separate tables, but separate schemas.

Comment: @chesh, My Question is, session object is bound to certain schema configurations right. If i need to save to another schema means whether same session can be useful??

Comment: @RahulThachilath, I think you are correct.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou my bad, mistaken schemas and tables.

Comment: You can write your own `Session` implementation to serve like a proxy between outer code and 2 "real" `Session`s aggregated inside it. I've never seen when one EntityManagerFactory served multiple schemas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered my question

Its not possible using same session for persist objects into two different schemas.

I have done like below:

I have create two hibernate configuration files for the two different schemas you need to persist the object.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Configuration config1 = new Configuration().configure(configfile1);
Configuration config2 = new Configuration().configure(configfile2);
```

I have opened the sessionfactory's by using both configuration instances

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = config1.buildSessionFactory(); 
SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = config2.buildSessionFactory();
```

I have opened two new sessions from sessionFactory instances

```
Session session1 = sessionFactory1.openSession();
Session session2 = sessionFactory2.openSession();
```

Now I have persisted the objects to two different schemas.

But Not sure whether this is correct way to handle.

Thanks